# Вред во всех смыслах(,) каких только возможно

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> От хлеба и жарки — вред во всех смыcлах(,) каких только возможно.

Comment: **Смылсы** - может смюсли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможные **варианты**:

(1) *От хлеба и жарки — вред во всех смыслах, **какие только возможны.***

(2) *От хлеба и жарки — вред во всех **что ни есть** смыслах.*

*От хлеба и жарки — вред во всех смыслах **что ни есть.***